# Что делают данные функции NumPy

Tags: python, изображения, нейронные-сети, numpy

Пытаюсь отредактировать [Unet](https://github.com/jocicmarko/ultrasound-nerve-segmentation/blob/master/train.py) нейронную сеть, в скрипте тренировки нашел следующие строки.

Можете объяснить - что они делают, и, если сами поймете, для чего

```
mean = np.mean(imgs_train)  # mean for data centering
std = np.std(imgs_train)    # std for data normalization

imgs_train -= mean
imgs_train /= std
```

np- это numpy

По english не понял описание данных функций

Cпacибo!

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам стоит браться за нейронные сети до того, как вы освоили numpy и познакомились с математическими понятиями "среднее арифметическое" и "стандартное отклонение"?

Comment: К сожалению, с pythonoм не очень дружен

Comment: А вот с теорией нейроннай сетей знаком

Comment: Так это  "среднее арифметическое" и "стандартное отклонение"

Comment: А я-то все думал - спасибо

Comment: а что именно вы хотите изменить в "Unet" и с какой целью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это попытка реализовать [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) ([нормализацию](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Standardization)) самому.

Лучше воспользоваться готовым решением:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

scaler = StandardScaler()
imgs_train = scaler.fit_transform(imgs_train)
```

PS при построении нейронных сетей очень часто данные нормализуют перед тем как "скормить" их на вход нейронной сети.